# Napster: Playback controls via keyboard?

Tags: browser-addons, music-streaming

Does Napster.com have any browser add-ons to allow me to control playback (play, pause, rewind, fastforward) from my keyboard?

I realize the browser would need to have focus and that's fine; I just get tired of having to search for the tab where I've got the Napster app, to interact with the playback controls.

I'd like access to them regardless of tab focus.